# mono for android: possibility to tell compiler not to use certain methods (winforms)

Tags: winforms, compiler-construction, mono, xamarin.android

Is there a possibility to make the compiler not check functions and methods that aren't used?
I'm working on an app that relies on code (in C#), in which members of the system.windows.forms.dll are used in some functions and methods. 
For instance:

```
protected IWin32Window parentWindow;
public virtual UserControl GetFirmwareInformation()
```

My app doesn't use this members, but it tries to load the dll anyway, and doesn't succeed, because, as I know, you can't use this dll. Now I'm looking for a workaround, because I can't throw the "forms-using methods" away.
One solution would be, to use precompiler directives, but I hope, that there is a more elegant way, because in the solution is also another c# desktop-program that can use the forms-dll.

Is there another solution?

Comment: Can't you just create a dummy assembly with these types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is to ship some files with your MonoDroid app which implement stubbed out versions of the missing interfaces, classes, enums and methods.

A neater solution might be to split those dependencies out of your source code somehow - either using some form of interface/injection or just simply using partial classes to split your code between multiple files. I'd personally go for some injection mechanism - but that's because I find using partial classes like that is quite similar to using `#define`.

Comment: The dummy assemblies are a good idea, also is the interface/injection solution, but this can be very time consuming. Another idea: Can I build a apk file myself, that contains the dll's I need, because from my point of view, the main problem is the compiling procedure, which checks the types and members even if they aren't used in my program.